# Cant change the label of my ChoiceChip with a variable

Tags: flutter, dart, class

So I have a widget where I display choicechips I wanted to change the text label of the chips by using a variable that change when I change the language. But because I guess of my list that is static it doesn't change.

When I try to delete the static word, I get an error in my home page

```
List<ChoiceChipData> choiceChips = ChoiceChips.all;
```

It says:

> Instance member 'all' can't be accessed using static access.

Where I display the chips

```
choiceChips
          .map((choiceChip) => ChoiceChip(
                labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: -1, bottom: -1),
                label: Text(choiceChip.label),
                labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 10),
                onSelected: (isSelected) => setState(() {
                  choiceChips = choiceChips.map((otherChip) {
                    final newChip = otherChip.copy(
                      isSelected: false,
                    );

                    return choiceChip == newChip
                        ? newChip.copy(isSelected: isSelected)
                        : newChip;
                  }).toList();

                  choice = choiceChip.value;
                }),
                selected: choiceChip.isSelected,
                selectedColor: const Color(0xFFFAA5A1),
                backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 38, 38),
              ))
          .toList(),
```

And here is my choicechips.dart

```
    class ChoiceChips {
  static var all = <ChoiceChipData>[
    ChoiceChipData(
      label: '$vtmnts',
      value: 'Vetement',
      isSelected: false,
      selectedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 129, 133, 136),
      textColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    ChoiceChipData(
      label: '$Nourriture',
      value: 'Nourriture',
      isSelected: false,
      selectedColor: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
    ),
}
```

And if you also want to check the choice chip data file here it is

```
class ChoiceChipData {
  var label;
  final String value;
  final bool isSelected;
  Color textColor;
  Color selectedColor;

  ChoiceChipData({
    required this.label,
    required this.value,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.textColor,
    required this.selectedColor,
  });

  ChoiceChipData copy({
    String? label,
    String? value,
    bool? isSelected,
    Color? textColor,
    Color? selectedColor,
  }) =>
      ChoiceChipData(
        label: label ?? this.label,
        value: value ?? this.value,
        isSelected: isSelected ?? this.isSelected,
        textColor: textColor ?? this.textColor,
        selectedColor: selectedColor ?? this.selectedColor,
      );

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ChoiceChipData &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          label == other.label &&
          value == other.value &&
          isSelected == other.isSelected &&
          textColor == other.textColor &&
          selectedColor == other.selectedColor;

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      label.hashCode ^
      value.hashCode ^
      isSelected.hashCode ^
      textColor.hashCode ^
      selectedColor.hashCode;
}
```